# Regex in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have to create a regex to validate ticket string in correct format.

**Ticket format:**

```
SFHD00002523003
```

It *starts with four alphabets* and *ends with 12 numeric characters*.

This is my code in my angular controller:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('[A-Z]{4}\\d{12}$');
console.log(pattern.test('SFHD00002523003');
```

Unfortunately, it is returning false for correct string, too.

Comment: Try `var pattern = /^[A-Z]{4}\d{12}$/;`

Comment: Unless I've forgotten how to count, those are not *12* digits in your test string... ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Thanks wiktor it is working

Comment: It is working thank you

Comment: You need to use `@` and then the user name without spaces to make sure the user is notified. I came back here by chance. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Need double backslash instead of single. like: `\\d` instead of `\d` in your expression

```
var pattern= new RegExp('([A-Z]){4}\\d{12}');
```

and your string has 11 numeric chars not 12

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the start of string anchor `^` to make sure you only match 16 character string. If you do not use it, you will get a match inside a 17+ character string that ends with your pattern.

Thus, use

```
var pattern = /^[A-Z]{4}\d{12}$/;
               ^
```